# Mechanize getting stuck on Javascript redirect page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, nokogiri, mechanize

I am using Mechanize and Nokogiri in my Ruby on Rails application to scrape our local printers administration panel to retrieve the number of printed pages in the printers lifetime.

I have the following rake task:

```
# Logs into printer admin page and retrieved counts.
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

# Create a new mechanize object
agent = Mechanize.new

# Load the printer admin page
page = agent.get("http://192.168.1.126/index.html?lang=1")

# Select the form with an action of index.cqi
form = agent.page.form_with(:action => "index.cgi")
form.radiobuttons_with(:id => '0x3fdb24153404')[1]

# Submit the form
page = form.submit form.buttons.first

pp page
```

That returns the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload=function(){setTimeout(function(){document.menu_link.submit();},0);}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="menu_link" action="index.html" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't seem to be able to select the form on the above page, and the script seems to stop at that page and not follow the redirect.

Is there a standard way of working with these kind of redirects? Maybe pausing the script until the redirect has taken place? Would it every allow the redirect to work?

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you selecting the form in the second page?

Comment: I just selected the form with a name of menu_link.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options. Either:

1. [Submit the form manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558856/mechanize-javascript)
2. Use [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Basically Mechanise will not run javascript, so you have to manually simulate the javascript running (option 1) or automate a real browser to do it (option 2)

Option 1 should be double if you just do a `POST` of `lang=1` instead of a get as that's all the form is doing.

I'd guess something like this:

```
page = agent.post('http://192.168.1.126/index.html', {
  "lang" => "1"
})
```

But I've never actually used Mechanize.

Comment: I'm already requesting lang=1 in the login page `page = agent.get("http://192.168.1.126/index.html?lang=1")` requesting it again gives a 404 error.

Comment: It's not a `get`, you need to be doing a `post`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add follow on redirects like this

```
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
```

Also if this is javascript controlled behaviour then you are in bad position because mechanize can't follow this. He don't executes js. You will have to see in js how he does it and emulate same call in mechanize.

But i think all you need to do is just

```
agent.post <url>
```

because he seems to be expecting post method.

There is hardcore alternative :) to use node-crawler in node.js
https://github.com/joshfire/node-crawler
it can evaluate javascript from client page server side.

Comment: If I do agent.post "index.html" it returns me to the login page?

Comment: There's no meta refresh in that HTML, it's a js form submit, totally different mechanism

Comment: The link to the node.js alternative is broken. I think it's been moved here https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler